# what is mean by search context in selenium and why webdriver is implementing the search context interface

Tags: selenium

what is mean by  Search Context in selenium? why web driver is implementing the search context interface. what is the relationship between search context and find element method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SearchContext** is an **Interface** which provides two important methods

1. **findElement**
2. **findElements**

**`WebDriver does not implements SearchContext it actaully extends it in-order to get capability to find element`**

**1. findElement**

```
WebElement findElement(By by)
```

> Find the first WebElement using the given method.

**Parameters:**
by - The locating mechanism

**Returns:**
The first matching element on the current context

**Throws:**
NoSuchElementException - If no matching elements are found

**2. findElements**

```
java.util.List<WebElement> findElements(By by)
```

> Find all elements within the current context using the given
>   mechanism.

**Parameters:**
by - The locating mechanism to use

**Returns:**
A list of all WebElements, or an empty list if nothing matches

**--->SearchContext definition**:

[image: SearchContext]

> Note : Even WebElement Interface also extends SearchContext interface